Review of PCB Schematic
Working on a small hobby project of a power socket whereby to allow the switch to be turned on / off both manually but also remotely via a ESP32C3.
I achieve this by converting the mains AC 100-240V to 24VDC 3A (this is for a separate circuit)  and then stepping down from the 24V to 12V (controls a relay coil for the mains) & 3.3V (power for the ESP32C3 which controls a transistor to allow the 12V to energise the relay coil)
I pulled a schematic off google for the 24VDC to 12V/3.3V schematic and modified it based on feedback from R/Printed Circuit Board on Reddit, meanwhile the AC 100-240V to 24V 3A circuit I reverse engineered a Chinese board bought from eBay, making only changes to the choke filter. The plan is for this circuit to be able to deal with circuits from around the globe with varying currents of 2.5A, 6A, 10A, 13A, 15A, 16A & 20A all within the 100-240V range.
I'm fairly confident the schematic will be able to handle between the 2.5A-13A range but I'm not too sure when it comes to 15A-20A range and wanted to get some feedback as to if there anything I need to change / add or remove from the schematic so it can handle the current, this circuit will be receiving the current all the time.
The 24V 3A separate circuit that I slightly mentioned is to go to a different circuit entirely whereby I'll be adding a potentiometer that will allow variable voltage between 1V-24V with a 3A current output for the purpose of DC barrel connectors e.g. powering Arduino projects

100-240VAC to 24VDC 3A schematic
Schematic was designed by myself by reverse engineering this Chinese board from Ebay: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/386704999723?var=653987465316 - Image for reference:


24VDC to 12VDC / 3.3VDC schematic
This schematic was designed by Homemade Circuits:
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/24-v-to-12-v-dc-converter-circuit/
Schematic for reference:

Everything after the output from the 2x 22uF capacitors I then designed and added to the schematic.
Any advice / feedback would be greatly appreciated.

@All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please! || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comments have been moved to this chatroom and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.
